# How to import stdIn.java and stdOut,java to resolve the regarding errors

Tags: java, jcreator

there are 4 standard input output files 
    StdIn.java
    StdOut.java
    StdRandom.java
    StdArrayIO.java
and i cant find them on my system and jcreator is generating the following errors:

```
    error: cannot find symbol
    StdOut.println();

    error: cannot find symbol
    int N = StdIn.readInt();

    error: cannot find symbol
    while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) and so
```

what i have already done is i downloaded a stdlib.jar file and i placed in the lib folder of jdk and also i have configured my IDE with the path  but its still not working.

Comment: Don't put your own jars in the JDK lib folder. Put them into a project-specific classpath folder.

Comment: My IDE has a project tab/menu for importing external libraries, I assume JCreator might also?  Check the manual.

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding jar in Jcreator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25578876/adding-jar-in-jcreator)

Answer (score -1):

Use `import` statement to those classes from jar that you use in the code. You should know the package name. IDE like eclipse do it if you hover unknown class and fix the error. See a Java [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) how to use `import` statement.