# adding jar in Jcreator

Tags: java, jar, jcreator

I want to read doc file by writing java code in jcreator editor . For this purpose , I want to use Apache POI jar file .

But I don't know how to add jar file in Jcreator editor . My file structure is like this :

[image]

Now I am referring using this code .

```
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.*;
import org.apache.poi.hpsf.DocumentSummaryInformation;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.HeaderStories;
```

But Jcreator is showing this error to me .

```
H:\Code For others\chat\docx file\ReadDocFileFromJava.java:1: package org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem does not exist
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.*;
^
H:\Code For others\chat\docx file\ReadDocFileFromJava.java:2: package org.apache.poi.hpsf does not exist
import org.apache.poi.hpsf.DocumentSummaryInformation;
                          ^
H:\Code For others\chat\docx file\ReadDocFileFromJava.java:3: package org.apache.poi.hwpf does not exist
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.*;
```

Why is the Jcreator showing this errors ? What do I do to remove this error ? [I am following thus tutorial for doc file reading .](http://www.sanjaal.com/downloads/java-code/ReadDocFileFromJava.java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Highlight the current project:

   [image: Image of highlighting the current project]
2. Click on the properties button:

   [image: Image of the properties button]
3. Click on the **`Required Libraries`** tab, then click **`New`**:

   [image: Image of the Add Library step]
4. Give the library an appropriate name, then click **`Add` -> `Add Archive`**:

   [image: Image of the specify library step]
5. Use the navigator to select the `.jar` file, then click **`OK`** on the Set Library window.
6. Ensure the libraries are checked, then click **`OK`**:

   [image: Image of the added libraries]

After this, the project should build correctly.

---

#### Note

I couldn't locate the library with the exact name yours had, but when I went looking for them I had to download both [POI Scratchpad](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-scratchpad/3.2-FINAL) and [Apache POI](http://download.nextag.com/apache/poi/release/bin/) in order to get it working, so **pay close attention to exactly which packages aren't found if it still doesn't build** when you follow the steps above